# Docker desktop CLI button behaviour

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

In Docker Desktop, there are multiple button for a container in the *Container / Apps* section.

[image: Docker Desktop Screenshot]

By default, This button will start a terminal session with command,

```
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh
```

In my  case I wanted it to execute `Bash (/bin/bash)` instead of `/bin/sh`.

Is there any possibilities for doing this?

Comment: Get any answer to this?